# Remove XML tags with Regex tools

Tags: xml, regex, perl, sed, awk

Here is a snippet of my XML file

```
<layoutItems>
            <behavior>Edit</behavior>
            <field>ID</field>
</layoutItems>
<layoutItems>
            <page>lastViewedAccount</page>
            <showLabel>false</showLabel>
            <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
            <width>100%</width>
</layoutItems>
<layoutItems>
            <behavior>Required</behavior>
            <field>Name</field>
</layoutItems>
```

I want to remove the section in the middle i.e

```
<layoutItems>
            <page>lastViewedAccount</page>
            <showLabel>false</showLabel>
            <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
            <width>100%</width>
</layoutItems>
```

This section can appear anywhere inside the file along with other tags.

What is the best way of using some string manipulation tool to remove this? I have been been trying my luck with `sed` but no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't suited for `sed` or `awk` anyways.  Use a XML parser.

Comment: I'm with @devnull . Handling xml using regexes will get messy

Comment: i was trying to avoid doing it through a program as this work was being done in bash. But I can do that.

Comment: @auny what is the key woard for the section in the middle?

Comment: You have to provide more information and example files (eg. on pastebin).

Comment: @captcha I dont see what more information to give but here is a gist https://gist.github.com/ahmedtalhakhan/5825062

Comment: @Endoro the keyword is "lastViewedAccount" in the page tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note: you should provide as much information as you can. Speaking generally parsing of [html](/questions/tagged/html), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [json](/questions/tagged/json) and so on with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) it **not** a good idea, use always a [html-parsing](/questions/tagged/html-parsing)- and  [xml-parsing](/questions/tagged/xml-parsing) -tool! The following [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) code may help you in the mean time. And so please also note: it may **FAIL** with other files and other structures! **Do not use in production!** I assume **NO** warranty!

```
sed -r '/<layoutItems>/{:ka;N;s#(</layoutItems>)#\1#;Tka;s/lastViewedAccount//;T;d}' file
```

---

Inputfile with 2 `lastViewedAccount` tags:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Layout xmlns="http://test.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <emailDefault>false</emailDefault>
        <headers>PersonalTagging</headers>
        <headers>PublicTagging</headers>
        <layoutSections>
            <customLabel>false</customLabel>
            <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
            <editHeading>true</editHeading>
            <label>Account Information</label>
            <layoutColumns>
                <layoutItems>
                    <page>lastViewedAccount</page>
                    <showLabel>false</showLabel>
                    <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
                    <width>100%</width>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>OwnerId</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Required</behavior>
                    <field>Name</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>ParentId</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>AccountNumber</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <page>lastViewedAccount</page>
                    <showLabel>false</showLabel>
                    <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
                    <width>100%</width>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>Site</field>
                </layoutItems>
            </layoutColumns>
      </layoutSections>
    </Layout>
```

---

Outputfile, `lastViewedAccount` tags removed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Layout xmlns="http://test.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <emailDefault>false</emailDefault>
        <headers>PersonalTagging</headers>
        <headers>PublicTagging</headers>
        <layoutSections>
            <customLabel>false</customLabel>
            <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
            <editHeading>true</editHeading>
            <label>Account Information</label>
            <layoutColumns>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>OwnerId</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Required</behavior>
                    <field>Name</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>ParentId</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>AccountNumber</field>
                </layoutItems>
                <layoutItems>
                    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                    <field>Site</field>
                </layoutItems>
            </layoutColumns>
      </layoutSections>
    </Layout>
```

Comment: Yes I know it should not be done this way and a parser tool should be used. Actually this item was required in a bash environment where I did not have the liberty of a program.

Answer (score 1):

GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr 'H; \#</layoutItems>#{x;s/(lastViewedAccount)/\1/;Tk;p;:k;x;s/.*//;x;s///;x;d}' file
```

---

```
$sed -nr 'H; \#</layoutItems>#{x;s/(lastViewedAccount)/\1/;Tk;p;:k;x;s/.*//;x;s///;x;d}' file

    <layoutItems>
            <page>lastViewedAccount</page>
            <showLabel>false</showLabel>
            <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
            <width>100%</width>
    </layoutItems>
```

Comment: This is just finding this portion and all the prior portion in the file i.e uptill this tag. Assume that there are other tags BEFORE this tag also. Also it is not removing it from the file