# How to replace a paragraph using sed command

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-processing

I have a license text in my Java file. I want to replace it with another license. I have plenty of java files to do that. How can I do it by using "sed" command or a bash script ?

Original license looks like,

```
/*
 * some txt
 * some txt
*/

package abc;
```

And I want to replace above license text to following,

```
/*
 * new license
 * new license
*/

package abc;
```

Comment: A similar question was already asked. This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454525/how-to-substitute-a-paragraph-in-file

Comment: I'd use a patch file, possibly with fuzzy matching turned up.

Comment: similar xml [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17213944/2098699).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do it... make sure you test first without using the -i flag, or else make sure you have recent backups of any of the files that match your find pattern.

```
for file in $(find /path -type f -name "*.jar" -exec egrep 'old license text' \;)
do
  sed -ri 's/old license text/new license text/g' ${file}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to `sed`, `awk`, et al.? It would be easier to do this in Perl:

```
perl -e 'undef $/;
  $_=<>;
  s|(/\*\n)[\s\S]*(\*/\s*package)|$1 * new license\n * new license\n$2|;
  print' in.txt
```